# How can I determine what codec is being used?

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth, codecs

[This forum comment](http://www.avforums.com/forums/6583863-post2.html) and this [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/205306/bluetooth-a2dp-profile-and-poor-sound-quality/205362#205362) answer suggest that the audio compression contributes to loss of quality. I've noticed that music played over my BT setup sometimes pitch bends in ways I don't remember the original doing, and I'm wondering if SBC has something to do with it.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 on a Mac Pro, connecting to a pair of [Sony DR-BT50's](http://www.sonystyle.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&productId=8198552921665095015). Is there a way to inspect which Bluetooth codec pulseaudio is using, what codecs both ends of the bluetooth link support?

Comment: I'd still appreciate an answer. I'm still using the headphones, still notice pitch bends from time to time. What should I do to keep it open?

Comment: You just did. If they close it later on just drop a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Normally compression doesn't change pitch, but depending on the program the hertz will. For instance if a 48000 file is played at 44100 the file will play more slowly, and will the pitch will drop. Just check the hertz your files are playing at.

Comment: If it were MP3 compression, I might be more inclined to look elsewhere. To address your point, the pitch *bends*, seemingly at random during songs rather than being constantly out of tune. I don't think this is a sample rate problem.